# How to determine in C++ typeof of template<class T> for deserialize data?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

## The problem:

```
How to determine typeof of **managed** template<class T> for deserialize data?
In C# a method to do this is typeof(T) but in C++ is ... ?
```

I will appreciate your collaboration.

line:

```
DataContractSerializer^ serializer = gcnew DataContractSerialize(typeof(T));
```

## Error Messages

Error   1   error C2275: 'T' : illegal use of this type as an expression    c:...\SerializationExtensions.h    33  1   iOffshoreSteadyStateEngine

Error   2   error C3861: 'typeof': identifier not found c:...\SerializationExtensions.h    33  1   iOffshoreSteadyStateEngine

## The code:

```
template<class T>
T SerializationExtensions<T>::Deserialize(System::String^ serialized)
{
    DataContractSerializer^ serializer = gcnew DataContractSerialize(typeof(T));
    StringReader^ reader = gcnew StringReader(serialized);
    XmlTextReader^ stm = gcnew XmlTextReader(reader);
    return (T)serializer->ReadObject(stm);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of C#'s `typeof(T)` would be `T::typeid`.  That goes for any type of course, not just generic types, so you could also do this: `System::String::typeid`.

Also, are you *sure* you want to use `template<class T>` and not `generic<class T>`?  You can read about the differences between them [at this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/branbray/archive/2003/11/19/51023.aspx).  One difference is that templates are created at compile time and generics are created at runtime.  Because of this, templates are not cross-language compatible where generics are.  There's a whole list in that blog post, I would suggest reading it if you're not sure.

[Here's the documentation on MSDN for typeid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwd9abya.aspx).

Comment: Christopher,
 
You hit the target.
Thank's !